# Alimentar links em imagens via PHP: Wordpress

Tags: php, array, wordpress, arraylist

to usando um tema atualmente que conta com a opção de portfolio, mas o mesmo não oferece nativamente uma opção pra adicionar link as imagens adicionadas.

Recorri a modificar o arquivo .PHP, mas não encontro uma forma de alimentar uma imagem em seguida da outra, pois está atribuindo o mesmo valor para todas de forma a concatenar

Segue os comandos:

ARRAY

```
$name = $arrayName = array (
'1' => 'https://google.com',
'2' => 'https://bing.com', );
```

Alimentar

```
<a href="<?php
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
echo $name[$i];}
```

já tentei de diversas formas mas todas concatenam os links.

Resultado até agora:

[image: links aparentes]

Percebi que existe uma variavel $id onde é mostrado o id das imagens.

Comment: Não use o `for` dentro do atributo `href`. Use-o desta forma, por exemplo: `<?php for (...) ?><a href="<?php echo $arr[$i]['href'] ?>"><?php echo $arr[$i]['text'] ?></a>`

Comment: Oks, mas em relação ao desenvolvimento do código pra alimentar sem concatenar, vc tem alguma ideia de como seria ?

Comment: Da forma que comentei, você deixaria de concatenar. Acho que sua dúvida é como tornar a adição de **link** de forma dinâmica.

Comment: Sim, exatamente, pois to tentando atribuir um link diferente pra cada imagem